# android how to select only one of button in adapter recycle view at view holder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How to select the only 1 button out of 3 button? I manage to set/unset the background color on selected button for currently. But not able to select the only one selected button.

Example btn1, btn2, btn3.
When I selected btn1, the btn1 background was change color, and btn2 and btn3 not affected. After that when I selected the btn2 again, the btn1 background color was unset and the btn2 background was change color. So at this time the btn2 is selected and btn1 and btn3 not selected.

**Below is my sample code:**

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Button mButton;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        parentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mButton= itemView.findViewById(R.id.mButton);
            }
        });
    }
}

       holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new DebouncedOnClickListener(500) {
            @Override
            public void onDebouncedClick(View v) {
                if(!holder.mButton.isSelected()){
                    holder.mButton.setSelected(true);
                    setSelectedButton(holder);
                }
                else{
                    holder.mButton.setSelected(false);
                    setSelectedButton(holder);
                }
            }
        });



    private void setSelectedButton(ViewHolder holder){
    if(holder.mButton.isSelected()){
        holder.mButton.setBackgroundColor(parentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.unread_notification));
    }
    else{
        holder.mButton.setBackgroundColor(parentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of setting color manually , you can use selector and if only one button is selected at a time. you can use radio buttons

Comment: don't need to use button only use  the view, which are you using in your recycle view. holder.your method name that all . hope it's help full.

Comment: @Prashant not even button, I mean if not button, how about other view like a view layout (Example constraint layout, relative layout, linear layout) which can perform click like button, if I selected this layout, I set the background color of this layout only our of 3 layout.

Comment: @chetanmahajan I was using linear layout, and I state button as an example

Comment: Do you need to select one button at a time ?
i.e if you select button one its color got change and other buttons colors remain same as the default ?
is this the case ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan yes yes ! That it

Comment: ok, can you show me layout ?

Comment: I need to know other buttons name ?

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan updated my code, there no other button name in recycleview lol, it depend on the list.size() to set the button.

Comment: Please show full code for this class so that it can be better understanding.

Comment: I want to watch your list and how you are updating data in it and how you are showing in recycle view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to implement selection into your RecyclerView. After some searching, I found that this website might be useful for you

https://medium.com/@maydin/multi-and-single-selection-in-recyclerview-d29587a7dee2

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use CheckBox instead of buttons like this -

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
 </RadioGroup>
```

And for the Button background -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#c7c7c7"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="#79ccff"
            android:endColor="#7900ca"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And for the background -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="50dp" />
<solid android:color="#c7c7c7" />
</shape>
```